# Set longer TTL for specified objects in s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a bucket that stores many of my application's logs and I want to be able to retain certain objects in the bucket. The objects do not have any tags associated with them except for the ones I want to retain, eg `tag:{permanent:true}`

How do I set the lifecycle policy so that I can retain permanent objects while other objects in the bucket follow the bucket level lifecycle policy.

Comment: Did you give Lambda a try?

Comment: Do you mind elaborating? @HùngNguyễn?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you can try something like this, add tags to all the objects like permanent:false which you do not want to retain.

So now you have objects with permanent:true or permanent:false.

Now create a lifecycle policy rule with `Limit the scope of this rule using one or more filter` and then add tags permanent:false and set action to permanently delete version of such objects.

Otherwise an alternate solution schedule a lambda which checks everyday and delete files which does not have tag permanent:true

Comment: If my s3 bucket has over 100,000 items in and I wanted to add a tag to each of the existing object it would be quite a heavy operation.

Comment: Not at all you can always do batch operation and perform batch tagging operation https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/storage/adding-and-removing-object-tags-with-s3-batch-operations/,  https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-amazon-s3-batch-operations/

and aws docs all thats the way https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/batch-ops-put-object-tagging.html

Comment: Just wanted to follow up did it worked?